# Getting the proper date from forms that are day/month/year

Tags: javascript

When writing a new date object with a string, one can write it as:

```
var someDay = new Date("12/01/2012");
```

This equals December 1st 2012.

However, what if the user has to fill in a date on a website where the format isn't month/day/year, but day/month/year? How would one go about creating a date object with the correct date then?

Comment: use a datepicker to make sure of the date format

Comment: You could give him multiple inputs, one for the Year , one for the Month etc.
and create the date like `new Date(year,month,day)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data as a string from another website, then you need to know the format in which that website provides you the date. There is no way around this because D-M-Y and M-D-Y are indistinguishable; even Y-M-D would be indistinguishable if they used a two-digit format for the year.

This hasn't been tested at all, but at worst the general idea should solve your problem.

```
var pattern = /^(\d+)\b(\d+)\b(\d+)$/;
if (!pattern.test(dateString))
    return null;
var matches = dateString.match(pattern);
if (siteUsesDMY)
    return new Date(matches[2], matches[1]-1, matches[0]);
if (siteUsesMDY)
    return new Date(matches[2], matches[0]-1, matches[1]);
...
```

Pattern: This pattern supports any numeric representation of the date, assuming it has a breaking character between each unit. If you need to support a website that doesn't have a breaking character, you would need a different pattern that matched that website's exact format (i.e.: site sends DDMMYYYY, then pattern would be `/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/`).

Also fixed the month parameter in date creation, as I just remembered that JavaScript uses 0-11 for months.